# Simple SIP phone in nodeJS without WebRTC

Tags: node.js, sip

Hi I need to implement something like SIP phone but with a 'classic' SIP without WebRTC.

Most JS libs focus on SIP over websockets and WebRTC, but in my infrastructure, I do not have WebSockets.
There are libs like JsSIP even with support for WebSockets in Node.js.

Maybe I should solution is to use software like webrtc2sip? But I fill this is little overcomplicated.

Some better solution?

Comment: Try to look at sip.js. It is very simple and supports UDP/TCP transports

Comment: @DmitryPoroh Also in node.js? As far as I know it support UDP/TCP transport only in browser enviorment

Comment: Sorry I mean this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sip 
It is not very popular but works for us in our test framework.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh Does it have support for media stream? Or maybe do you know how to integrate media stream support?

Comment: No it does not. It is not even full SIP stack (only transport/transaction layers). I've added simple RTP stream by myself. It is not very difficult when you know what you do.